# Prolog - Rules are correct, but not outputting the way it's supposed to?

Tags: prolog, failure-slice

**Clue**

Four guests (Colonel Mustard, Professor Plum, Miss Scarlett, Ms. Green) attend a  dinner party at the home of Mr. Boddy. Suddenly, the lights go out! When they come  back, Mr Boddy lies dead in the middle of the table. Everyone is a suspect. Upon further examination, the following facts come to light:

- Mr Boddy was having an affair with Ms. Green.
- Professor Plum is married to Ms. Green.
- Mr. Boddy was very rich.
- Colonel Mustard is very greedy.
- Miss Scarlett was also having an affair with Mr. Boddy.

There are two possible motives for the murder:

- Hatred: Someone hates someone else if that other person is having an affair with  his/her spouse.
- Greed: Someone is willing to commit murder if they are greedy and not rich, and the victim is rich.

Part A: Write the above facts and rules in your Prolog program. Use the following  names for the people: colMustard, profPlum, missScarlet, msGreen, mrBoddy. Be careful  about how you encode (or don’t encode) symmetric relationships like marriage - you  don’t want infinite loops! `married(X,Y) :- married(Y,X) % INFINITE LOOP`

```
?-suspect(Killer,mrBoddy)
Killer = suspect_name_1
Killer = suspect_name_2
etc.
```

Part B: Write a predicate, suspect/2, that determines who the suspects may be, i.e. who  had a motive.

```
?-suspect(Killer,mrBoddy)
Killer = unique_suspect.
```

Part C: Add a single factto your database that will result in there being a unique suspect. 
Clearly indicate this line in your source comments so that it can be removed/added for 
grading.

```
?-suspect(Killer,mrBoddy)
Killer = unique_suspect.
```

---

Whenever I type in

```
suspect(Killer,mrBoddy).
```

I get

```
suspect(Killer,mrBoddy).
Killer = profPlum
```

I'm missing

```
Killer = colMustard.
```

Here's my source.

```
%8) Clue

%facts

affair(mrBoddy,msGreen).
affair(missScarlett, mrBoddy).
affair(X,Y) :- affair(X,Y), affair(Y,X).

married(profPlum, msGreen).
married(X,Y) :- married(X,Y), married(Y,X).

rich(mrBoddy).
greedy(colMustard).

%rules

hate(X,Y) :- married(X,Spouse), affair(Y,Spouse).
greed(X,Y) :- greedy(X), not(rich(X)), rich(Y).


%suspect

suspect(X,Y):- hate(X,Y).
suspect(X,Y):- greed(X,Y).
```

Comment: Did you ask prolog about another killer? By using ; after you get the first solution printed?

Comment: You will get into an endless loop when trying to get the second solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the recursive rules of the predicates `affair/2` `and married/2`. Attempting to use them easily leads to an endless loop (i.e. until the stack memory is exhausted). You must use a different predicate in each case to represent that if X is having an affair with Y, then Y is having an affair with X. You also need to change your definition of the `suspect/2` predicate to call those new predicates.

To better understand why you get an endless loop, use the trace facilities of your Prolog system. Try:

```
?- trace, suspect(Killer, mrBoddy).
```

and go step by step.

Comment: Thanks! I caught the infinite loop when I finally got it to try to output the second suspect.

I'm having another problem now. How do I go about section C of this problem?

I don't see how I could add a single fact to negate the other two current facts and only return a single suspect.

Comment: There aren't enough facts to rule out either suspect.

Comment: If I add something like "willKill :- greedy", how would I change suspect to choose willkill as a definitive answer over returning people with just motives?

Comment: I actually did mean Part C. I just edited it back into the original question. 

So I added a rule/fact "willKill :- greedy". (Not sure if that's the proper approach to this problem) I tried changing suspect to "suspect(X,Y) :- willKill(X) -> X; (hate(X,Y); greed(X,Y))." I get an exception error. Also I realized that if I comment out "willKill", it'll completely break my program.

Comment: You can add a `person/1` predicate in order to list all persons in the puzzle and then rewrite the new `willKill/1` as `willKill(X) :- person(X), ...`. That would avoid the exception, which is due to the variable `X` not being instantiated when you call `willKill(X)`. But you will still have two solutions as a single solution can not be inferred from the limited set of facts.

Answer (score 3):

There are two kinds of problems with your program. One is on the **procedural level**: you observed that Prolog loops; the other is on the logical level — Prolog people call this rather the **declarative level**. Since the first annoying thing is this endless loop, let's first narrow that down. Actually we get:

```
?- suspect(Killer,mrBoddy).
Killer = profPlum ;
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

You have now several options to narrow down this problem. Either, go with the other answer and call up a tracer. While the tracer might show you the actual culprit it might very well intersperse it with many irrelevant steps. So many that your mind will overflow.

The other option is to manually modify your program by adding goals **`false`** into your program. I will add as many **`false`** goals as I can while still getting a loop.  The big advantage is that this way you will see in your source the actual culprit (or to be more precise one of potentially many such culprits).<sup>1</sup> After trying a bit, this is what I got as [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice):

```
?- suspect(Killer,mrBoddy), false.

married(profPlum, msGreen) :- false.
married(X,Y) :- married(X,Y), false, married(Y,X).

hate(X,Y) :- married(X,Spouse), false, affair(Y,Spouse).

suspect(X,Y):- hate(X,Y), false.
suspect(X,Y):- false, greed(X,Y).
```

All remaining parts of your program were irrelevant, that is, they are no longer used. So essentially the rule

```
married(X,Y) :- married(X,Y), married(Y,X).
```

is the culprit.

Now, for the **declarative part** of it. What does this rule mean anyway? To understand it, I will interpret `:-` as an implication. So provided what is written on the right-hand side is true, we conclude what is written on the left-hand side. In this case:

> Provided `X` is married to `Y` and `Y` is married to `X`
>   we can conclude that
>   `X` is married to `Y`.

This conclusion concluded what we have assumed to be true anyway. So it does not define anything new, logically. You can just remove the rule to get same results — declaratively. So `married(profPlum, msGreen)` holds but `married(msGreen, profPlum)` does not. In other words, your rules are not correct, as you claim.

To resolve this problem, remove the rule, rename all facts to `husband_wife/2` and add the definition

```
married(M,F) :- husband_wife(M,F).
married(F,M) :- husband_wife(M,F).
```

So the actual deeper problem here was a logical error. In addition to that Prolog's proof mechanism is very simplistic, turning this into a loop. But that is not much more than a welcome excuse to the original logical problem.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sub>**Footnotes**:
1 This method only works for pure, monotonic fragments. Non-monotonic constructs like `not/1` or `(\+)/1` must not appear in the fragment.

2 This example is of interest to @larsmans.</sub>

Comment: I disagree with your assertion that this is a logical error. `m(x,y) ∧ m(y,x) → m(x,y)` is superfluous, but superfluous axioms don't change the theory that the program expresses (it might in linear logic, but Prolog is based on standard first-order logic).

Comment: @larsmans: The OP's claim was that "the rules are correct", but, for OP's purpose they were incorrect. That is all I claim. And it often (not always, indeed) happens that such errors go hand-in-hand with procedural error.s

Comment: The rule in question *is* correct, logically, as is every tautology. It's not correct procedurally, because it causes depth-first inference to go into a loop. A breadth-first inference algorithm (optional in SICStus and not too hard to implement for other Prologs) would be unaffected.

Comment: @larsmans: With your particular use of "correct", there are no incorrect programs (except some unsound step, like succeeding for `X=s(X)`). Breadth-first alone does not solve this problem at all. And: are you sure you mean SICStus?

Comment: @larsmans: You did not mean: bottom-up instead of breadth-first?

Comment: I thought there was a breadth-first option in SICStus, but I can't find it in the manual now (and I haven't used it for years). Anyway, IIRC it is possible to build a breadth-first (or iterative deepening) meta-interpreter that can prove any true theorem of a pure Prolog program, although it may go into an infinite loop for falsehoods.

Comment: @larsman: *That* is possible, but it could not handle the program in question.

Comment: Because of the negation, I suppose, but it could handle the tautological rule for `married` if the query is true. Re: my definition of "correct", no, there are incorrect programs even without infinite terms. Suppose the model of the program is one in which `[[foo]] = {x}`, then `foo(y).` is an incorrect program.

Comment: @larsman: bfs can only produce all answers (already for monotonic programs), but it cannot stop! In any case, `married/2` was incorrectly defined because `married(msGreen, profPlum).` was not true.